# Apache2 crash after SSL install

Tags: apache-2.2, ubuntu, ssl, ssl-certificate

I'm trying to install ssl on my apache2 ubuntu 14.04. After I install all my credentials and restart my apache I get

> caught SIGTERM shutdown

There is no more error or explanation.
I created a folder in etc/apache2 called ssl and generated my csr & key there using this command:

```
openssl req -new -newkey rsa:2048 -nodes -keyout yourdomain.key -out yourdomain.csr
```

Here is my 000-default.conf in sites-available:

my 000-default:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName mydomain.com/
Redirect / h t t p s ://mydomain.com/
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:443>

ServerName mydomain.com:443
SSLEngine on
SSLCertificateFile /etc/apache2/ssl/962dfc9e10c76031.crt
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/apache2/ssl/mydomain.com.key
SSLCertificateChainFile  /etc/apache2/ssl/gd_bundle-g2-g1.crt
ServerAdmin admin@domain.com
DocumentRoot /var/www/html
 <Directory /var/www/html/>
     AllowOverride All
     order allow,deny
     allow from all
   </Directory

ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

</VirtualHost>
```

Then I call

```
a2enmod ssl
```

and restart apache. But I get SIGTERM shutdown.
Note: I used cloudfalre on strict mode

Comment: That message is what Apache emits when it is being shut down normally.  There will be other log entries *somewhere* indicating what is going wrong on startup.

Comment: @womble where can I find these log files? I can only see var/log/apache2

Comment: When all else fails turn to the find command.  For example:  `find / -mount -name error.log`

Comment: @Gene thanks for the command. I only have mysql/error.log and apache2/error.log

Comment: Does either `httpd -t` or `apache2ctl configtest` (both commands do the same thing) report anything unusual?

Comment: @Gene apache2ctl says Syntax ok. But the other one says No command "httpd" found did you mean "http" "https" "xttpd"

Comment: Ah, yeah, those funny little distribution differences.  `apache2 -t` == `httpd -t` == `apache2ctl configtest`

Comment: @Gene I see. I don't know what is wrong with this ssl its driving me nuts

Comment: Is the certificate issued by Cloudflare? Also, just remove the ":443" from the "ServerName" directive, and also the "/".

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, the explanation for this type of error gets logged to the master Apache error log file.  Take a look at that and see what error it's giving you and I expect that will quickly lead you to the solution.  If there's no log entry, check /var/log/messages as well, and if none in either of those places, try starting apache using strace and see if any of the last messages it outputs give any hint as to what's going on.

Comment: can you give me abit more hint on where this error log is located? I checked var/log/apache2/error.log but this is the one that has SIGTERM shutdown. I checked my VHOST and it is pointing to APACHE_LOG_DIR. Where is this located? Btw i dont have /var/log/messages

Comment: @HiradRoshandel That looks like you might have the correct location.  I think the master error log is defined by the ErrorLog directive that's outside of any VirtualHost tag - you could look at your conf file and see what it says.  On Ubuntu try /var/log/syslog instead of /var/log/messages.

Comment: nothing in syslog about ssl. I check apache2.conf and this is set ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log. all of them are using APACHE_LOG_DIR

Comment: @HiradRoshandel Please try the strace suggestion then and see if there is anything useful from that.